# Problem with multiple views iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app I'm building that has multiple views and everything looks good until I try to compile. I get an error in the method that I use to switch between views. It says there is no property `.view` for the controller. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

```
-(void)setToHomeView:(UIView *)fromView
{
 [fromView removeFromSuperview];
 [window addSubview:ThisViewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "ThisViewController" the name of your class perhaps?  You need to use an instance of the class instead.

Comment: Thanks dude works like a charm now. Turned out if was using the class not an instance.